# pre-trained model checkpoint.pt

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a pre-trained model.  This model uses 9 input but I want to use 55 input. There is a checkpoint.pt paramaters file. How can I change this file?

> RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for Network:     size
> mismatch for fc.0.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1600,
> 9]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1600,
> 55]).     size mismatch for fc.6.weight: copying a param with shape
> torch.Size([9, 400]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is
> torch.Size([55, 400]).    size mismatch for fc.6.bias: copying a param
> with shape torch.Size([9]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model
> is torch.Size([55]).

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Please include an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Well, you cannot. A Model trained for N features cannot be used for M features, with N != M.

Comment: Thanks, How can I edit a checkpoint.pt file?